# Magento table rate not working after migration

Tags: magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

We migrated from 1.4 to 1.6
I am not sure if this is a problem in the migration but our table rate shipping is not worked.

I have this 2 examples;

This one works

```
Country    Region/State     Zip/Postal Code    Weight (and above)   Shipping Price
USA        *                *                  80                   145
```

This one does not work

```
Country    Region/State     Zip/Postal Code    Weight (and above)   Shipping Price
USA        AL               *                  80                   145
```

I have checked blogs, etc, and I dont see a problem on the files.
Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying them separately or is it part of the same file?

Comment: I tried them as separate files.

Comment: Were you sure to set AL as the state when you were checking out? (I know, obvious...but I have to ask to be certain!)

Comment: yes I did, I used zip code 36310 AL.  http://www.mongabay.com/igapo/zip_codes/AL.htm any ideas?

Comment: in your db, check the "dest_zip" field of "shipping_tablerate": is it empty or 0?

Comment: ah no sorry, I just checked, there is an * there.

Comment: the strange thing I noticed, that table has 1317 rows, and our file only has 1 row, it looks like it keeps the history and never deletes the old entries when a new file is uploaded? what would u suggest?

Comment: I noticed for some website ids, its *, but for other website ids is empty.    I also noticed dest_region_id is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the condition sql for tablerate checks (among other thing) that `dest_zip = ''` (cfr **Mage_Shipping_Model_Mysql4_Carrier_Tablerate** line 135).
As you have * for this field the condition isn't met.
Best solution would be to edit the db, replacing ***** by nothing (empty field).
In my case I couldn't (dunno why, the db kept replacing my empty string with 0), so I had to override the class to add one line:

```
"dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = :postcode",
"dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = :region_id AND dest_zip = ''",
"dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = ''",
"dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = '0'",//added line
"dest_country_id = :country_id AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = :postcode",
"dest_country_id = '0' AND dest_region_id = 0 AND dest_zip = ''",
```

HTH

Comment: Hi, Indeed it works, after I remove the * and put empty it works fine, however,even if I remove the * from the file, the * appears again on the database.  You said u had to override the class, can you please explain what you mean? I am not a php developer or magento developer

Comment: what class should I override?

Comment: @developers, please don't look at this.  
you're not a php developer, so let go with the easy-and-nasty way. Copy your file `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Mysql4/Carrier/Tablerate.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Mysql4/Carrier/Tablerate.php`, find in it the code I've pasted in my answer and add the line I indicate as the one I added.

Comment: I can turn dest_zip to "" in my DB but still the table rate doesnt work.  I upgraded from 1.4 to 1.7 and the $0+ rate shows fine, but the $100+ rate etc wont work.  If I upload the csv enough times it works, and then stops working a few days later.  Any ideas?